# Handle JMS commit failure after JDBC commit is success

Tags: database, transactions, jms, activemq-artemis

In my application I read from JMS and write to database. To handle this situation [the ActiveMQ documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/should-i-use-xa) has following:

```
onMessage
try {
   if I have not processed this message successfully before {
   do some stuff in the database / with EJBs etc
   jdbc.commit() (unless auto-commit is enabled on the JDBC)
}
jms.commit()
} catch (Exception e) {
   jms.rollback()
}
```

My question is let's say we face issue when doing `jms.commit()`, then we rollback the jms session. But our db commit already done. Since we rolledback jms session, queue will send that data again to consumer which will result in duplicate data in database. We have experienced this on failover scenario on ActiveMQ Artemis queue. Is there a alternative way i can handle this without causing duplicates on db or data loss ?

Comment: Have you already ruled out using XA? Also, when you say "two-phase commit" are you referring to XA or something else? If you're not using XA then you're not actually using a 2-phase commit. Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically this situation would be handled using XA transactions (which use a [2-phase commit protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol)). This is extremely common in Java EE where you have an MDB consuming a message and then working with a database or another JMS provider. All the work is done atomically so if any one part fails (e.g. MDB consuming the message, database work, sending message to another provider) then they all fail so that all the data across systems remains consistent.

You appear to be eschewing XA transactions (not sure why) and manually committing or rolling back individual JMS and JDBC transactions. There's always going to be a (fairly high) risk of data inconsistency with this approach. How you deal with it will depend on your specific constraints.

To be clear, the pseudo-code from the ActiveMQ documentation which you cited is *not* using 2-phase commit.